# Is there a way to group only sequential rows in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Imagine we have table *t* with the following data set:

```
n
-
1
1
2
2
2
1
1
3
2
2
```

GROUP BY clause in SQLite groups all items with the same value, so if we simply use

```
select n, count(*) from t group by n
```

result will be the following:

```
n   count(*)
1   4
2   5
3   1
```

What I need instead of grouping everything, is to group only neighbor items, i.e. group until meet another n. So basically need to count how many times in a row each value appears.

Result should look like this:

```
n   count
1   2
2   3
1   2
3   1
2   2
```

Is this possible in terms of SQLite? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is a gaps and islands problem.  To have any chance of solving it you would first need to provide another column which generates the ordering in your data set.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for this comment, it actually helped a lot then.